# Struggling with printing values from structures in C

Tags: c, structure

I'm having a bit of trouble with structures in C. I think the problem is with pointers. Here is what my program is supposed to do;
Read an input data, such as this;

```
Name: Hello
Gender: Male
Age: 60

Name: Hello1
Gender: Male
Age: 13

Name: Hello2
Gender: Female
Age: 10

Name: Hello3
Gender: Male
Age: 20
```

I want the program to read the the words after the ':', e.g Hello and put that value into
a structure. So an index[1] of a structure should contain hello, male, 60, for example.

When I print values inside the while loop, it is printing fine. But when I try and print values of structures outside the while loop, it does not work. I get this as output;

```
¿6Q ¿6Q  60
 ↑  13
 æ £  10
 §☺  ☺  20
```

It is printing the age for each element, but not any of the others. I been struggling with this for a while, and have no idea why this is the case.  Thankyou for your help;
Here is my code:

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please flag it as such. Also, tell me why you do `char line[80];` and then `fgets(line, 100,fr)`.

Comment: There are elements in this that apply to a homework I'm doing. This I did to generally get to grips with structures. How do i flag it as homework? That was a mistake, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, please do mark the homework as homework.

Second, as Mr Lister indicated, you are allocating variable `line` to be 80 chars long, but you're reading up to 100 characters from the file into it - with long lines this will cause problems.  You should read no more than 79 characters (leaving 1 for the `\0` at the end).

Now about "printing", I think your problem is in these lines:

```
p[nameIndex].name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(line));
p[nameIndex].gender = (char*)malloc(sizeof(line));
p[nameIndex].age = (char*)malloc(sizeof(line));
```

As `line` is essentially a `char *`, `sizeof(line)` will not give you the results you're expecting.  Instead, you should use `strlen` function - and not here but rather at the place where you're copying the data.  Your code should look something like this:

```
switch(i)
{
    case 1:
        p[nameIndex].name = (char*)malloc(strlen(tmp) + 1);
        strcpy(p[nameIndex].name, temp);
        break;
    case 2:
        p[nameIndex].gender = (char*)malloc(strlen(tmp) + 1);
        strcpy(p[nameIndex].gender, temp);
        break;
    case 3:
        p[nameIndex].age = (char*)malloc(strlen(tmp) + 1);
        strcpy(p[nameIndex].age, temp);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Of course, this is assuming that each character takes 1 byte of storage.  Otherwise, you should use `(strlen(tmp) + 1) * sizeof(char)` to get the right allocation.

Comment: @AleksG Since `line` is an array, not a pointer, `sizeof(line)` is 80! You can test for yourself.

Comment: @user1005253 When you select tags for your question, add tag "homework"